# How to save file in the EDGE browser without unneccessary undescores?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frontend, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to save the file throw the edge with `window.navigator.msSaveOrOpen(blob, name)`. On screen below you can see the value of the `name`

[image]

I'm press run and edge suggest me to save this file, but with underscores in the name:
[image]

The problem that after downloading you can't open a pdf immidiatelly, firstly you have to remove '_' from the end of the name. Any idea how to fix it?

**More details**
The angularjs is used and this how the blob has been created:

```
   ...
   .then(response => {
                return {
                    name: response.headers('Content-Disposition').split('=')[1],
                    blob: new Blob([response.data], { type: 'application/pdf' })
                };
            });
```

Comment: The filename in the header is stated using quotes; not sure how that gets turned into underscores but that's probably what's happening. In other words, the text stored in `name` is not just `AdverseTemplate coi_coi.pdf` but `"AdverseTemplate coi_coi.pdf"`

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks, it seems now so obvious, but I was blind and sure that quotes are from the edge debugger :) You can post answer if want.